# Finding the Smallest Possible Perimeter of a Certain Triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying for some quizzes when a wild question appears. It goes like this:

> Triangle $ABC$ have integer side length with $AB = AC.$ Let $I$ be the intersection of the bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C.$
>   Suppose that $BI = 8.$ Find the smallest possible perimeter of $\Delta ABC.$

My work:

I imagined the problem like this:
[image]

I realized that the only triangles that has these attributes (Triangle $ABC$ have integer side length with $AB = AC$) are the $45^o-45^o-90^o$ triangles 
and the $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangles. Later, I discovered that the perimeter of a $45^o-45^o-90^o$ triangle is higher than the perimeter of $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangle,
 so I think, the triangle above describes a $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangle. Redrawing the figure again to incorporate those revelations and adding other details:

[image]

I know that perimeter $P$ of a triangle with sides $a, b$ and $c$ is $P = a + b + c.$ Since $AB = AC$, then $P = a + 2c$. Then I need the perimeter $P$ be in terms 
of $\theta$ so that I will apply differentiation to a single variable, which is $\theta.$

Gettng the $a$:

Using the cosine law to the green triangle above: 
$$a^2 = (8)^2 + (8)^2 - 2(8)(8) \cos (105^o)$$
$$a = 12.69$$

Gettng the $c$:

Using the sine law to the red triangle above:
$$\frac{c}{\sin 127.5^o} = \frac{8}{\sin 15}$$
$$c = 24.52$$

So.....$a = 12.69$ and $c = 24.52$.

Oh wait....I was supposed to get the perimeter is terms of $\theta$, but it turns out, 
that I can get the sides. My logic is this: You can make the $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangle bigger or smaller at your free will, just like zooming in or out. 
But we had  $BI = 8,$ which essentially makes the  $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangle impossible to make it bigger or smaller, because  $BI = 8$ controls the 
other attributes of the $75^o-75^o-30^o$ triangle, which can be seen if you look hardly enough.

The perimeter I got is $P = 61.73$ But my book said that the smaller possible perimeter of $\Delta ABC$ is 108.

I exhausted my know-how in that problem. How do you get the perimeter of 108?

Comment: $45-45-90$ will not have integer sides.  Your solution does not work because $a$ is not an integer, so the angles must be something else.

Comment: @RossMillikan So is the $75 - 75 - 30$  triangle? But those two triangles were fit to the description, maybe we can make their sides to be in integer values?

Comment: @RossMillikan How will I find these expression of angles? I doubt if this is a right question....XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it experimentally.  Clearly $a \lt 16$.  We can write $\frac a2=8 \cos \frac B2$ by dropping a perpendicular from $I$ to the base.  We can solve that for $B=2 \arccos \frac a{16}$, then get $A=\pi-2B$ and $c=\frac a{2 \sin \frac A2}$  Now just plugging in values for $a$ we find only $a=12, c=48$ and a perimeter of $108$ works.  The base angle is about $82.82^\circ$

Comment: What was your illustration, or drawing, used to get the perimeter?